# How to connect Sqlserver 2008 in Django?

Tags: django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'NAME': 'CVH_Dev',
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
        'use_legacy_date_fields': 'True'
    }
}
```

I was tried above code . but it shows error message.

**Error Messgae:**
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 134, in    load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sqlserver_ado' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
**Error was: No module named util**

please tell me how to connect SQL server 2008 to my django project..
now I m using SQL server2008R2

Answer (score 1):

Django doesn't support MSSql out of the box. I would suggest trying an external package, like [django-mssql](https://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: yes, i already installed django-mssql, but it dosen't work. Can you tell me how to use it..

Comment: Are you sure you have set up your environment properly? Error message suggests that django-mssql is not found in the sys.path. Make sure to double check that by using `pip list`.

Comment: yes i installed. see this                                                                    Django (1.10.3)
django-mssql (1.6.2)
django-sqlserver (1.7)
pip (9.0.1)
pyodbc (3.0.10)
setuptools (20.10.1)
sql-server.pyodbc (1.0)

Answer (score 0):

From the code that I see you are trying to use third party package  Django MSSQL
which needs these settings. To make these settings available for Django you first need to:-

```
pip install django-mssql
```

For further reference you can read:-
http://django-mssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: i want to connect with sql server